# Kivy settings do not update the .ini in android

Tags: python, android, kivy, settings, configparser

**In short**:
My settingsfile (vocab.ini) just gets updated on my laptop, somehow not on Android (maybe permissions?).

Hi there!

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have an application which has its settings saved in an external .ini file (vocab.ini). Whenever something is changed in the settings, the implemented `on_config_change()` method will reinitialize all the screens with that changed .ini file in order to update all my screens accordingly and also make changes persistent (after app closes for example).
The logic for this is already there, but somehow it just works on my laptop - not on my smartphone.

That leads to my first question:

I don't really understand why the vocab.ini file is updated (on my laptop - it does not update on android) after I change something in the app since I haven't implemented anything like `config.set()` and/or `config.write()` in my code. Somehow the `on_config_change()` must imply that since I can see live on my laptop how the content changes whenever I click on any of the six available options.

My second question would be in general how to implement such a logic that this will also work on Android/any smartphone since I must be missing sth. there or have a misunderstanding of how the settings panel in kivy works.

Here is a short code snippet which should help you to reproduce the problem.

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from settingsjson import settings_json
from kivy.config import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

def get_config():
    config.read('vocab.ini')

class MainWindow(Screen):
    label = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Initialized Main!")
        get_config()
        self.label = "Current config: {}".format(config.get('example','optionsexample'))

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

KV = Builder.load_file("vocabApp.kv")

class vocabApp(App):    
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('example', {
            'optionsexample': 'HSK1'})
        config.read('vocab.ini')

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Vocab Settings',
                                self.config,
                                data=settings_json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section,
                         key, value):
        print("Re-initialize all screens")

        ### For android debugging ###
        f = open("vocab.ini", "r")
        print(f.read())
        ###                       ###
        for sc in self.root.ids.sm.screen_names:
            self.root.ids.sm.get_screen(sc).__init__()

    def build(self):
        return KV

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vocabApp().run()
```

vocabApp.kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: sm
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ActionBar:
        background_image: ''
        background_color: (0.53, 0.808, 0.98, 1)
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_release: app.open_settings()
        
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'
    Label:
        id: label
        text: root.label
```

settingsjson.py

```
import json

settings_json = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'example title'},
    {'type': 'options',
     'title': 'HSK Level',
     'desc': 'Choose the difficulty (HSK1 to HSK6)',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'optionsexample',
     'options': ['HSK1', 'HSK2', 'HSK3', 'HSK4', 'HSK5', 'HSK6']}
])
```

vocab.ini:

```
[example]
optionsexample = HSK1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will fix it, but here is how I have handled it:

```
from kivy.utils import platform
import os.path


def get_config_file_name():
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.storage import app_storage_path
        return os.path.join(app_storage_path(), 'vocab.ini')
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'vocab.ini')


from kivy.config import Config


def permissions_callback_storage(requests, grants):
    if grants[0]:
        Config.read(get_config_file_name())


if platform == 'android':
    perms = ['android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']
    from android.permissions import request_permissions
    request_permissions(perms, callback=permissions_callback_storage)
else:
    Config.read(get_config_file_name())
```

Comment: Hello John!
Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. Probably I implemented it wrong but I'm also a bit confused as you're using the default kivy config if I understand that correct. Especially in my vocabApp class things get messed up, because there is no ConfigParser.
However I solved it by manually reading and editing the file via regex, although that might be not the most elegant way of doing it :)

Comment: @MaGi: You're very confused. That's fair enough. Kivy's `Settings` API itself is very confusing, poorly documented, and overengineered to the hilt. The issue here is that you're trying to split your settings between Kivy's default configuration file `~/.kivy/config.ini` and your own app-specific configuration file `vocab.ini`. Kivy expects you to write *all* of your settings to the same file. Splitting settings between multiple files is absolutely unsupported (as it should be). To rename your configuration file, just trivially define `def get_application_config(): return 'vocab.ini'`.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by adding manual reading and writing code to the `on_config_change()` method of the `vocabApp()` class:

```
def on_config_change(self, config, section,
                     key, value):
    print("Re-initialize all screens")

    with open("vocab.ini", "r") as f:
        subbed = re.sub("{}(.*)".format(key), "{} = {}".format(key, value), f.read())

    with open("vocab.ini", "w") as f:
        f.write(subbed)

    for sc in self.root.ids.sm.screen_names:
        self.root.ids.sm.get_screen(sc).__init__()
```