# My code works in Xcode simulator but it doesn't in iPhone

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, permission-denied

I have a very simple program, which works python kivy.

In that program I read and write json files.

Everything is fine with every simulator in Xcode Version 13.4.

However when I connect my Phone it can read the json file but can't write in it.

It says;

```
File "/Users/batuhan/programs/kivy-ios/2800-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 429, in secom
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C2508051-03DA-40EC-8587-A40D8B922055/2800.app/YourApp/savelist1.json'
2022-05-19 20:14:09.322995+0300 2800[3486:1776834] Application quit abnormally!
2022-05-19 20:14:09.416628+0300 2800[3486:1776834] Leaving
```

As I understand so far it is all about build settings in Xcode.

Because as MacBook user I can write in that json file in simulator and everything works perfect.

I need to give permission to write json file for every user, staff or everyone.

I am just a beginner in Xcode, I think it is related with those settings;

[image]

The json file is in same directory with main.py

Comment: When you deploy to a real device your app is packaged into a bundle (basically a zip file). You can't write to this bundle. You will need to change your app so that it first copies the file to your app's documents directory where it can be written

Comment: Dear Paulw11 where should I make the change ?

Comment: You will need to write more code.  When your app launches you need to check if `savelist1.json` exists in your documents directory.  If it doesn't you need to copy the file from your bundle (the file your code currently reads)

Comment: Dear Paulw11, thank you very much for your support. Right now I am trying to configure .json files. like this one; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647112/kivy-settings-do-not-update-the-ini-in-android. However, ı could create an .ini file with my App class as well. I still do not know how to add .json file to .ini file directory.

Comment: I havent ever used Kivy, but I can point you to the Swift code that explains what you need to do - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-find-the-users-documents-directory You need to use `FileManager` or `NSFileManager` to get the path to your documents directory.  Then you can read the file from your bundle and write it into that directory. From then on you can ignore the bundle and just use the file in your documents directory

Comment: The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399958/kivy-error-on-ios-using-json-file-for-high-score/24412173#24412173) might help